# How to ignore SSL Certificate Java

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, jvm

I keep getting this exception "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address xxx.xxx.xx.xxx found" on a http get request. I've tried pretty much everything already. Is there a JVM argument that i can use to ignore SSL certificates?

These are the VM arguments running on my JBOSS.

"-Dprogram.name=JBossTools: Red Hat JBoss EAP 6.1+" -server -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000

Comment: If you don't want it secure ehy are you using SSL?

Comment: @user207421 had to try something out at work. I know it's not optimal.

Comment: It’s *insecure*. That’s a completely different thing from non-optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use [this class](https://gist.github.com/franciscocpg/89c2989a74d72e5fc62f)?

Add it to your project and then make a static call.

```
 static {
        SSLUtilities.trustAllHostnames();
        SSLUtilities.trustAllHttpsCertificates();
    }
```

Comment: And then take it out again before it leaks into production.